# Implicit reference to an enclosing class in Java

Tags: java

Lets say I have a `Outer` class. Lets say there is a non static member class `Inner`. So an `Outer` instance will have  a reference to an instance of `Inner` if the `Outer` class declares a field of type `Inner` and that is by definition. But how does Inner instance also has a ***implicit*** reference to `Outer`? When is this association created?

Comment: "So an Outer instance always has a reference to an instance of Inner and that is by definition." - this is not true.

Comment: @millimoose  Why is it not true?

Comment: An instance of the outer class will only hold a reference to an instance of the inner class if the outer class explicitly declares a field for it.

Comment: @Geek It's not true because it just does not happen at all? An `Outer` instance can create as many instances of `Inner` as it wishes explicitly, but there isn't any implicit instance thereof.

Comment: @millimoose See if the edit makes sense.   I am talking of implicit reference the other way round. ie inner having implicit reference to outer

Comment: @Geek Right, so you didn't mean an implicit reference from `Outer` to `Inner`. For the other way around, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14777967/41655).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Java language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)

> An instance i of a direct inner class C of a class O is associated
>   with an instance of O, known as the immediately enclosing instance of
>   i. The immediately enclosing instance of an object, if any, is
>   determined when the object is created (§15.9.2).

Answer (score 4):

You have it the other way around:

```
public class Outer {

    void foo() {
        // In this Outer method, we have no implicit instance of Inner.
        innerbar(); // Compiler error: The method bar() is undefined for the type Outer
        Inner.this.innerbar();// Compiler error: No enclosing instance of the type Outer.Inner is accessible in scope

        // instead, one has to create explicitly instance of Inner:

        Inner inner1 = new Inner();
        Inner inner2 = new Inner();

        inner1.innerbar(); // fine!
    }


    class Inner {
        void innerbar() {};

        void callOuter () {
            // But Inner has an implicit reference to Outer.
            callMe();
            // it works also through Outer.this
            Outer.this.callMe();
        }
    }

    void callMe() {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
class Outer {

    class Inner {
        void printOuterThis() {
            System.out.println(Outer.this);
        }
    }

}

Outer.Inner oi = new Outer().new Inner();
```

is mostly equivalent to this:

```
class Outer {

    static class Inner {
        Outer outerThis;

        public Inner(Outer outerThis) {
            this.outerThis = outerThis;
        }

        void printOuterThis() {
            System.out.println(outerThis);
        }
    }
}

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer.Inner oi = new Outer.Inner(new Outer());
    }
}
```

The compiler automatically emits code that does what happens in the second: a field (`this$0` that holds the value of `Outer.this`) for the implicit reference and transforms all constructors of `Inner` and calls to them to add initialisation of this field.

Comment: You can't actually compile the second example, though, can you?

Comment: @Alex There's a bunch of errors in it, I was writing it from memory. Should be okay now.

Comment: Right, I changed the second sample to match what the decompiler tells me is really happening.